# VB parsing strings and placing into text boxes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a task I am trying to complete, but cant think how to approach it.

Here is the example:

I have a text file with preferences in it. I read the file and find text on a particular line like this:

```
 If InStr(sLine, "avidDirectory") Then
```

This is my line in the text file:

```
 avidDirectory "S:\Avid MediaFiles\" "D:\Avid MediaFiles\" "Z:\Avid MediaFiles\"
```

What I need to do is read each string between the quoations marks and place each one in a text box.

I have 5 texts boxes to use if there are 5 different directories above (only three in the example above)

So I guess I need to capture the text between the quotation marks, create a new string from it, and place that string into a text box

ie;
   string 1 = textbox1.txt 
etc

How would I approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: Old function calls like Instr() in .Net code is a code smell.  For that matter, so are type-prefixes.  That "If" line in modern code should look like this:  `If line.Contains("avidDirectory") Then`

Comment: Whats a code smell Joel?

Comment: A code smell is something that isn't exactly _wrong_, per se, but still looks odd enough to make you think you might need to take a closer look at that code and the surrounding code just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Windows application and add a button and five text boxes to the form you will be started with and replace the code of the form with this code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim txt As String = "avidDirectory ""S:\Avid MediaFiles\"" ""D:\Avid MediaFiles\"" ""Z:\Avid MediaFiles\"""
        Dim insideAQuotation As Boolean = False
        Dim array(5) As String
        Dim currentString As Integer = 0


        For i = 1 To Len(txt)
            If Mid(txt, i, 1) = Chr(34) And insideAQuotation Then
                insideAQuotation = False
                currentString += 1
            ElseIf Mid(txt, i, 1) = Chr(34) And insideAQuotation = False Then
                insideAQuotation = True
            End If

            If insideAQuotation Then
                If Mid(txt, i, 1) <> Chr(34) Then    'This is to avoid the quotation marks inside the text boxes.
                    array(currentString) &= Mid(txt, i, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Me.TextBox1.Text = array(0)
        Me.TextBox2.Text = array(1)
        Me.TextBox3.Text = array(2)
        Me.TextBox4.Text = array(3)
        Me.TextBox5.Text = array(4)



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, wasnt expecting a whole code, but this is perfect I think. Dan